# Не присваивается значение элементу массива

Tags: javascript, массивы

На выходе получаю те элементы которые были изначально. То есть присваивание не срабатывает.

```js
function deleteOtherChars(arr) {
  for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    for (var j = 0; j < arr[i].length; j++) {
      arr[i][j] = 'd';

      console.log(arr[i][j]);
    }
  }

  //console.log(arr);
}

var arr = ['aaaaa','bbbbb', 'ccccc'];

deleteOtherChars(arr);
```

Comment: уточните что должно быть на выходе

Comment: мне нужно заменить n-й элемент строки, в массиве

Comment: Вы пытаетесь сделать присвоение символу в строке, а не элементу массива. JS так не работает. В JS строка это не массив символов.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В js не получится заменить символ строки обратившись к нему как к элементу массива. Символы строки можно менять так

```
var string = 'test',

result = string.replace(string[1], 'o');

console.log (result) // tost
```

UPDATE

способ выше не верен, при одинаковых символах будет заменено первое вхождение, можно поступить так

```
function replaceChar (string, index, char){
    return string.slice(0,index)+char+string.slice(index+1)
}
```

Comment: Спасибо, пол дня мучился))

Comment: `result = string.replace(string[3], 'o');` — как вы думаете, что получится?

Answer (score 1):

Еще один вариант, использовать при замене регулярное выражение:

```js
function replaceCharByIndex(string, index, char) {
  var regExp = new RegExp('(.{' + index + '})(.)');
  return string.replace(regExp, '$1' + char);
}

console.log(replaceCharByIndex('test',1,'o'));
console.log(replaceCharByIndex('test',3,'o'));
```